# How do I substitute a generic class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a generic class in TypeScript and I want to define a new type that makes it easier to reuse the class name.

```
class Foo<T> {
...
}

type FooNumber = Foo<number>;
type FooString = Foo<string>;
```

If I create an object of `FooNumber` I get the following error message:

```js
new FooNumber();
'FooNumber' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

In C++ I would use a `decltype`. Is this possible in TypeScript as well?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes

Comment: AFAIU, the example in the docs creates an instance of the object, that's not what I need

Comment: you posted an error showing an issue creating the instance of an object? what is your question then?

Comment: But your code is doing exactly creating an instance of an object. What do you actually need?

Comment: The example uses `GenericNumber<string>();` to create an object, and I need 
a type like `GenericNumberString`

Comment: Types and values are different, especially since types get erased from emitted JavaScript.  Instead of types `FooString` and `FooNumber`, you need *values* named `FooString` and `FooNumber`.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlxKQN) work for you?  I can write up an answer if so; otherwise please let me know what use case is not met.

Answer (score 2):

```
class FooNumber extends Foo<number>{}
```

Comment: unless you are extending the logic between FooNumber and Foo, you do not need to do this. If inheritance is what op is wanting then this question is badly worded

Comment: technically not a bad idea. I will think about it, thanks!

Comment: @about14sheep: while inheritance may look overkill just to specify the generic, it is totally valid. In other languages (typically Java) this happens a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer works, I cant help but think that inheritance may be overkill for generic types.

They way the question is worded it appears the OP would like to be able to change the type of a property based on the type of a constructor input. In the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes), they discuss how to make generic classes. I think you can simply get the functionality you are looking for by passing the type in with the `Foo` constructor:

```js
class Foo<T> {
    value: T
    constructor(x: T) {
        this.value = x 
    }
}

const fooNum = new Foo<number>(123)
const fooStr = new Foo<string>("hello")

console.log(typeof fooNum.value) //"number"
console.log(typeof fooStr.value) //"string"
```

If I misunderstood the question and this was not the behavior you were looking for I apologize.